# why am I getting error that x:type is not define in xaml page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a xaml that I copied from another project into a class library. I am getting this error (and several other errors)

```
The type 'x:Type' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  \WPF\Resources\Resources\Styles\DataGridStyle.xaml
```

I checked and I referenced these assemblies in my class library:

```
  Microsoft.CSharp
  PresentationCore
  PresentationFramework
  PresentationFramework.Aero
  System
  System.core
  System.Data
  System.Data.DataSetExtension
  System.xml
  System.xml.linq
  WindowsBase
```

Should I include any other assemblies?

Comment: Is x: declared in your xaml? thats what its looking for. can you post your XAML?

Comment: it is very big xaml. Yes it is defined:  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

Comment: It's WPF right? Not Windows Phone or WinRT?

Comment: Yes. the xaml was part of a wpf application and I moved it to a new class library. So the xaml is correct, but project setting is not correct. Maybe I am missing an assembly reference.

Comment: is this the first compiler error?

Comment: There are several, but all of them related to unknown items. As I said, since the same xaml worked in another wpf project, I think the problem is project setting.

Comment: is that a compiler error? or intellisense error or runtime? normaly you get only one compiler error and the intellisense "errors" are often misleading in wpf. can you pls post the one(first) compiler or runtime error?

Answer (score 3):

Add `System.xaml` assembly to your ClassLibrary project's "**References**".